# ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN error in android button

Tags: java, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, android-button

Im trying to get data to my device from realtime db.
Here this code:

```
load.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
String a = emailString.replace(".", "");
Query recentPostsQuery = database.child("User").child(a);
ValueEventListener listener = new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
User value = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
Toast.makeText(More.this, "User-loaded data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
PreferenceConfig.T_62_M1_2_1(getApplicationContext(), T_62_M1_2_1);

PreferenceConfig.T_62_MK(getApplicationContext(), T_62_MK);

PreferenceConfig.T_62_MB(getApplicationContext(), T_62_MB);

PreferenceConfig.T_62_MB_1(getApplicationContext(), T_62_MB_1);

PreferenceConfig.T_62_MD(getApplicationContext(), T_62_MD);
}
}

@Override
public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
Toast.makeText(More.this,"Err",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
};
```

database.addValueEventListener(listener);
But... When i pressed button i see just this error:

```
 ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
```

Someone told me that i need add this in xml file of layout:

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Also i saw that i need to add:

```
<View
android:id="@+id/workaround_button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignStart="@+id/load_from_db"
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/load_from_db"
android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/load_from_db"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/load_from_db" />
<Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="load"
android:id="@+id/load_from_db"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:layout_below="@+id/save"/>
```

But nothing happaned...
What i need to do to fix it?

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?